# How to get task output using xcom variable?

Tags: airflow

I am trying to get task output so that i can assign it to a variable but use it on my next task. Any help would be appreciated .. Online suggestion points to pythonOperator example.

Comment: did you try the PythonOperator example?

Comment: @kaxil I am using custom operators. Currently I am achieving this by setting variable value and using that variable value in my next task. PythonOperator allows to read xcom value but I am looking for an approach where i push value (xcom) using custom operator and i can pull the value in next task..If i pass previous task ID then i can achieve that within operator but i wanted to see how can i achieve that in same DAG ... any example will be helpful